# Prevent angular component from re-rendering unless data has changed

Tags: angular, typescript, braintree

I have a problem with an angular component that connects to a third party API [PayPal BrainTree](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/start/hosted-fields) that dynamically adds an iframe to the component body. I need to keep the connection and the underlying html persistent and not disconnect from the api.

The component in question is related to multiple payment options, with a single option connecting to the third party api. The problem arises when another request is fired to refresh the payment methods, when this occurs the payment options are re-rendered which is disconnecting the API and removing the iframe from the component, before establishing a new connection and creating a new iframe.

[Here is a working Minimum viable example for reference.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-payment-methods-braintree-issue)

The basics of the rendering is

1. API request to get payment options is made
2. Payment options are rendered in a loop
3. Payment option is rendered, different component for LazyPaymentOptionComponent and normal PaymentOptionComponent
4. If payment Options are checked again the whole component is re-rendered disconnecting the API.

```html
<div *ngFor="let option in payments$ | async">
  <app-lazy-payment-option *ngIf="option.lazy"></app-lazy-payment-option>
  <app-payment-option *ngIf="!option.lazy"></app-payment-option>
</div>
```

In the LazyPaymentOption the connection to the third party payment API is made during the ngAfterViewInit

```js
@Component(...)
class LazyPaymentOptionComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.thirdPartyService.connect().subscribe();
  }
}
```

Ideally I need to prevent the LazyPaymentOption from destroying and re-rendering, in React i would use shouldComponentUpdate but I have not found anything like that in Angular at the component level.

I have found the ChangeDetectorRef but I can't seem to get that to prevent the component from destroying and re-rendering eg. I was hoping I could use `this.cd.detatch()` to prevent unloading and re-rendering the component.

```js
@Component(...)
class LazyPaymentOptionComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private thirdPartyService: ThirdPartyService
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.thirdPartyService.connect().subscribe(() => {
      // attempt to detach from change detection so the component doesn't re-render
      this.cd.detatch();
    });
  }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent the render cycle until I manually make it happen? Or anything else I should try, I'm 2 days deep into this issue and not sure where I can look.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a change detection strategy for that.

```
@Component({
    selector: '...',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: `...`
})
export class ...Component  {
```

The default change detection strategy actually rerenders components a lot. Pretty much whenever something happens that potentially could change a value of one of your getters, it will rerender.

By contrast, the `OnPush` strategy only rerenders when

- an input value of your component has actually changed
- or an `| async` pipe has a new value

Due to this behavior, it also won't detect **some** changes automatically. (e.g. the value of a getter has changed.) And in those cases you may have to rerender it forcefully.

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

onInit() {
  setInterval( () => {
    // this is something an OnPush strategy won't detect.
    this.counter++;

    // so you have to mark it for a rerender.
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }, 1000);
}
```

In general, I try to make most of my components to work with the `OnPush` strategy, for performance reasons.

Using that as a rule of thumb, you could end up writing a lot of `markForCheck`. That soundn't be the case actually. You should more actively use async pipes. e.g. in the previous example, you could model the counter as a `BehaviorSubject`.

```
public counter$ = new BehaviorSubject();   

// note: in template file, use "counter$ | async"

onInit() {
  let counter = 0;
  setInterval( () => {
    // this is something an OnPush strategy won't detect.
    counter++;
    this.counter$.next(counter);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Looking at it from the other side. Every `setTimeout` can actually rerender tons of components (*the ones with the default change detection strategy*). If you know in advance that it doesn't need to rerender any components, you could in fact block that as well:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone)

onInit() {

  // make the contained changes undetectable for angular.
  ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.counter++;
    }, 1000);

  });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, I'll try out your suggestion. Thanks for you help!

Comment: It's unfortunately still re-rendering. It seems that the change detection is triggering at a higher level, maybe I can move this higher in the hierarchy outside of the loop. Do you know if angular has a virtual DOM like React and Vue?

Comment: @synthet1c Angular does have a virtual DOM. ;  Having said that, in this case it's probably not only the `LazyPaymentOptionComponent` that needs to use `OnPush`, but it's probably the component that uses it (the one that wraps it), or the component around that. You may want to put all those on a `OnPush` strategy for a moment, and then re-enable re-renders as you go.

Comment: I moved it up to the wrapping `payments.component.ts` which contains the api request for payment methods and the loop through the payment options. It's still not working there. I'll have to dig through the documentation to understand exactly how the `OnPush` strategy works. Re the virtual DOM. I can see that the entire `PaymentsComponent` is destroyed and re-rendered not just the individual options so it doesn't look as efficient as React in calculating the DOM tree changes.

Comment: @synthet1c yes, well that's the thing with Angular. It tries to dumb things down by automatically enabling "2-way-binding". Easy to learn. Unfortunately, the 2-way-binding has no way to predict the outcome of a getter. So, as soon as you start referencing getters in the view, it will re-render aggressively. And then `OnPush` disables that. However if the wrapping component doesn't use `OnPush` then its still possible that the entire wrapping component is being re-rendered. Basically, I would suggest to also put `OnPush` on the PaymentsComponent and the component that uses your payments-comp.

Comment: @synthet1c and as you mentioned, if you see unnecessary flickering in the DOM tree of entire components, then surely you can further optimize it.